# How can I create a CSS selector that requires multiple classes in an element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I have the following LESS:

```
        button {
            background: #eee;
            border: 1px solid #BBB;
            color: #000;

            &:hover:not(.nohover) {
                background: #0007d5;
                border: 1px solid #0007d5;
                color: white;
            }

            &.correct {
                background-color: #00ff00;
                border: 1px solid #00ff00;
            }

            &.incorrect {
                background-color: #ff0000;
            }

            &.current {
                background-color: #000;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                color: white !important;
            }
        }
```

I'm confused about how to add multiple additional classes. How can I make it so that if the button has a class of current and correct that the text color will be #00ff00 and if the classes are current and incorrect the text color will be #ff0000?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With LESS you can use the & selector to keep stacking class selectors to the same element.

```
button {
    &.current {
        background-color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        color: white !important;
        &.correct {
            // add CSS here for button.current.correct
        }
        &.incorrect {
            // add CSS here for button.current.incorrect
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you don't like the deeper nesting:

```
button {
    &.current.correct {
        // add CSS here for button.current.correct
    }
    &.current.incorrect {
        // add CSS here for button.current.incorrect
    }
}
```